# Show that the complex function is non-holomorphic everywhere.....

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can someone help me with this question:

Show that complex function $f(z) = (z^2)*\overline{z}$ is non-holomorphic everywhere.

Comment: Write down the real and imaginary parts of f(z) in terms of x and y where z = x+iy. Show that they do not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations for any x, y.

Comment: How can I show that they do not satisfy the Cauchy Reimann equations?

Comment: Compute their partial derivatives, and plug those results into the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: An edit changed "non-holomorphic everywhere" to "not holomorphic everywhere".  Which is it?

Comment: It is non-holomorphic

Comment: I just edited: user223305 please check, should it be the square of $z$ multiplied by the conjugate of $z$ as I have made it?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: The Cauchy Riemann equations simultaneously hold only at the origin. I think they need to hold in a neighborhood of a point to get holomorphic at that point, however...

Comment: I'm confused now

Comment: Still stuck on this. I know how to show that z^2 on its own is non-holomorphic but what do I do about the conjugate of z part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holomorphic at a point $z_0$ means that the function is complex differentiable at every point in a neighborhood of $z_0$. You can either check this by computing the limit of the difference quotient, or use the Cauchy Riemann DGL. In my opinion, the latter is easier. Note that $f(z)=z^2\cdot\overline{z}=z\cdot z\overline{z}=z|z|^2$ and therefore $\Re(f(z))=|z|^2\Re(z)$ and $\Im(f(z))=|z|^2\Im(z)$. If you write $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then $u(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)x$ and $v(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)y$. It is now easy to check that the CR-DGL only hold at $z=0$, and since they don't hold in a neighborhood of $z=0$, $f$ cannot be holomorphic there (and neither at any $z\neq0$).

---

To see that the CR-DGL are only satisfied at $z=0$, just calculate $u_x=3x^2+y^2, u_y=2xy, v_x=2xy, v_y=x^2+3y^2$. The CR-DGL say that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. This gives $3x^2+y^2=x^2+3y^2$ and $2xy=-2xy$. The first equality gives $2x^2=2y^2$ and therefore $|x|=|y|$. The last equality gives $xy=0$. Consequently, $x=0=y$.

---

The easiest way, however, would be using Wirtinger derivatives. Since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(z)=z^2=0$ iff $z=0$ immediately yields the above result.

Comment: How can I check that the Cauchy Riemann only holds at z = 0?

Comment: Added more detail.